# What is the diffrence b/w Bijective function and one-to-one correspondence?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

In there any diffrence between bijective function and one-to-one correspondence.why we use somewhere bijective and somewhere one-to-one correspondence.

Comment: They are synonyms.

Comment: I cannot think of any difference between them, even in terms of informal meaning, except perhaps that "bijection" is often used more in contexts where we care about the function and "one-to-one correspondence" shows up a bit more in contexts where we just care that such a function exists - but it's worth noting that it's rare to mix the terms: authors generally choose one term and use it exclusively (since it's confusing if a text uses two terms to refer to the exact same thing).

Comment: The two locutions may come from prior uses; there are still some older books in Group Theory, for example, that use “isomorphism” to mean “isomorphism onto the image”, i.e., injective function, and use “correspondence” to mean bijection. But currently, they mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same and can be used interchangeably: both of these terms mean that the function is both *injective* and *surjective*. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection.

On the other hand, to say that a function $f$ is "one-to-one" just means it is injective, namely whenever we have $f(x)=f(y)$ we must also have $x=y$.